# Get price variable in checkout.tpl in opencart 2.2

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed opencart 2.2 and want to change the color of "Confirm your Order" button depending on the total price of the cart so I have my function the change the color if `$price_to_test_the_function` is lower or greater than x in `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.tpl`.
How can I get the price value from Opencart in checkout.tpl?

```
$price_to_test_the_function = ??
```

Comment: Is this just for color change, no other purpose? I would suggest doing it in pure JS, client side: grab the `td` with total, convert to number and change button color depending on the value. Otherwise you need to modify core code in controller and AJAX handling script in tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, for something as frivolous as color change I wouldn't bother channeling this through controller to tpl etc. As far as I understand, this has pure presentational value and is not affecting application or business logic.

In *catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\checkout.tpl*

before

```
//--></script>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Just add the following few lines and you are good to go. This also is likely to work across more Opencart 2.X versions then tinkering with controller and tpl core code.

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    var val = $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').find('table').find('td').last().text().trim();
    if (val){
        sVal = val.replace(/[^\d\.]/,'');
        var iVal = parseFloat(sVal);
        if (iVal > 50){
            $('#button-confirm').css({
                'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #E66C25, #943A18)'
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Logics can be different for everyone mate. Opencart already has too much jquery and javascript. You can go for the jquery and ajax method, but i'd prefer controller method. Simple 3 lines of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't do in the tpl. You can check for it in controller. Before you pass the variable through `currency format`, it is available in float. So you can check over there, and declare a new variable `$data['color']`. Then you can use that variable in your tpl file.